# What will be the formula for conditional formatting to highlight the duplicates in horizontally for multiple rows in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight the duplicate cell horizontally (not vertically) for multiple rows in Google Sheet.
Please Note: I don't want to find duplicates between rows. I want to highlight each row individually up to 100 rows may be.

Comment: are those duplicates per row or per whole set? also, all duplicate instances or only 2+? share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula in conditional formating**

```
=COUNTIF($1:$1,$1:$1)>1
```

[image]

### Test 100 columns

[image]